# chown -R user:user .* changes permissions backwards: is this the correct behaviour?

Tags: permissions, filesystem, chown, hidden-files

I got into a lot of trouble when changing the permission of a folder `myfolder` residing in `/`.
I issued the command

```
sudo chown -R luca:luca /myfolder/.*
```

My intention was to change ownership of all the hidden files in `/myfolder`.

Unfortunately I realized that also the ownership of `/` was changed, which of course left me with a broken system. I think this happened because `..` matches `.*`, but still seems weird to me.

Is changing the parent directory the correct behaviour or should I file a bug report?

If it was my mistake in using chown, what are the best practices to use to prevent changing the ownership of system folders and files?

Comment: This is intended behaviour as `..` matches `.*`

Comment: `.*` means any file that ends with `.` 
`*.` means any file that starts with `.`

Comment: @NikTh It the other way round!

Comment: Well one best practice might be not modifying `/` directly (creating folders, removing, etc) unless utterly necessary (open a question for what you wanted to achieve). Also is dangerous using wildcards+root privileges because, more often than not, you are not 100% sure what is been affected by the wildcard.

Comment: Related: [chmod all files (including hidden files) in a directory in Linux (not recursively)](http://serverfault.com/q/211690/51929)

Comment: @Lekensteyn is not related.. I wanted to change the ownership (not the mod).. and `only` of the hidden files and folders.. not of all files..

Comment: @LucaCerone It is related, `chmod` and `chown` are similar commands, both start with `ch`, contains an `o` and have two other similar letters (`n` and `m`). </literal> Seriously, they are both of the form: `[cmd] -R [mode or user] [one or more files]`. Some solutions offered on that question work for your case too, for instance [this one from Sean Reifschneider](http://serverfault.com/a/211815/51929) (in the middle). [This answer](http://serverfault.com/a/211712/51929) is also applicable to hidden files *only* by removing the glob pattern for non-hidden files.

Comment: @Lekensteyn thanks for the links, (I didn't know about shopt..)  I still think though that the purpose of AskUbuntu is provide help to newbies the that can not know that chown and chmod have the same syntax :) (I discovered it today :))

Comment: @LucaCerone That link is from Serverfault.com by the way; I find myself sometimes running `chmod 0:0 [file]` instead of `chown 0:0` due to the similarity. Are you wondering what `0:0` means? [RTFM](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/chown.1)! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that the command line is expanded (interpreted) by the shell before being executed

```
sudo chown -R luca:luca /myfolder/.*
```

is interpreted first as :

```
sudo chown -R luca:luca /myfolder/.  /myfolder/.. /myfolder/.adobe  /myfolder/.bash_history
```

note the `/myfolder/..` in your command line

`chown -R luca:luca /myfolder/..` is equivalent to  `chown -R luca:luca /`
that makes the chown running "backwards"

Use `echo /myfolder/.*` when you use "*" to verify .

Comment: @Emmanuel: why would you use xargs and find when the -R option is sufficient?

Comment: @Emmanuel: thanks! can you expand a bit about the find and xargs?

Comment: @LucaCerone I am not sure why you accepted this one, it *recursively* changes **all** files in `/myfolder`. The `find` command is superfluous and breaks with filenames containing whitespace. (if you want to recursively change files, `find /myfolder | xargs chown luca:luca` is similar to `chown -R luca:luca /myfolder`).

Comment: Lekensteyn is right I forgot to grep ^.

Comment: @Lekensteyn I changed the find to not match space

Comment: @LucaCerone correction made

Comment: @January the find command alone lets you check first if you are modifying the files you want, then you can do the find piped into xargs

Comment: @Lekensteyn I voted this because clearly explains how the filenames are expanded... and helped me understand where things went wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Well. Command line as root is very powerful. Read some of [these](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/horror.txt) classics. And yes, `.*` matching to `..` is exactly what is intended. Dot is not a special character. It is a convention. By convention, files that start with a dot are hidden from the default view when listing a directory -- nothing less, and nothing more. By convention, the inode leading to the current directory gets the `.` name and the inode leading to the parent directory gets the `..` name.

What you should have done was

```
chown -R luca:luca /myfolder
```

Did I mention that there is nothing special about the file names that start with a dot? Recursive `chown` doesn't think so.

Right now, you might be able to rescue some of the functionality by changing the ownership back to root. In the long run, you will probably have to reinstall the system, though.

As a general rule:

1. Avoid working as root.
2. If you work as root, read each command twice before hitting Enter.
3. If you are unsure about expansion, try it first with a "safe" command (like `echo .*`).
4. Do not work as root.
5. There are many tasks that can be performed safely using a graphical interface (your problem is an example of such a task).
6. Did I mention that you should avoid using the root account?

Comment: I didn't want to change the ownership of all the files in the folder... only of the hidden files..

Comment: OK, my bad then. In that case, `chown -R luca:luca /myfolder/.[^.]*` I think

Comment: `echo .*` is a good way of trying out the expansion. It'll show you exactly what the shell sees. `ls .*` can be a bit more confusing, as it'll go down directories (`ls -d .*` might be better, but might as well just use `echo .*`)

Comment: @RobieBasak good point!